# R dtw package: cumulative cost matrix decreases at some points along the path?

Tags: r, statistics

I am exploring the results of Dynamic Time Warping as implemented in the dtw package.  While doing some sanity checks I came across a result which I cannot rationalize.  At some points along the warp path, the cumulative distance appears to decrease.  Example below:

```
mat= structure(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.06,0.09,0.11,0.13,0.16,0.18,0.2,0.22,0.24,0.24,0.22,0.22,0.22,0.22,0.21,0.2,0.19,0.2,0.23,0.29,0.34,0.41,0.51,0.62,0.73,0.82,0.9,0.95,1,1,1,0.92,0.92,0.89,0.89,0.84,0.79,0.7,0.53,0.37,0.23,0.17,0.13,0.11,0.09,0.08,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.08,0.08,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.13,0.15,0.19,0.22,0.27,0.29,0.34,0.35,0.36,0.35,0.38,0.37,0.37,0.32,0.3,0.26,0.24,0.21,0.19,0.17,0.15,0.14,0.12,0.1,0.09,0.09,0.08,0.08,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.03,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.04,0.04,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.02,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.1,0.12,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.17,0.19,0.2,0.21,0.22,0.24,0.23,0.24,0.26,0.3,0.32,0.33,0.35,0.39,0.44,0.49,0.55,0.61,0.67,0.71,0.76,0.83,0.9,0.97,1,0.99,0.86,0.68,0.5,0.41,0.33,0.28,0.23,0.2,0.17,0.15,0.13,0.12,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.13,0.15,0.17,0.18,0.2,0.21,0.24,0.25,0.28,0.29,0.32,0.35,0.36,0.34,0.32,0.3,0.3,0.28,0.26,0.23,0.22,0.19,0.17,0.15,0.14,0.12,0.1,0.09,0.09,0.08,0.08,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.06,0.06,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04),.Dim=c(149L,2L))
tw = dtw(mat[,1], mat[,2], keep.internals = T, step.pattern = asymmetricP05)
```

.

```
d.phi = tw$costMatrix[ cbind(tw$index1, tw$index2) ]

which(diff(d.phi) < 0)
# 45  50  53  54  61  70  72  73  80  81 101 115 117 120 124 125 129 139 184 189 191 193

plot(diff(d.phi))
```

[image: diff(d.phi)]

This should not be the case, as d_phi is a sum of non-negative distance measures, multiplied by m which takes values 0 or 1.

[image: d_phi]
[image: d]

**I doubt this is an implementation problem with the dtw package, so where am I making a mistake?**

Another sanity check (taken from the reference below) plots the path on top of the costMatrix.  Below is plotted indices 45:55 in which we see 45, 50, 53, and 54 have decreasing cumulative cost (from above `diff(d.phi)`). The first transition is `diff(d.phi)[45]`.

```
i = 45:55
i1 = tw$index1[i]
i2 = tw$index2[i]
r= range(c(i1,i2))
s = r[1]:r[2]

ccm <- tw$costMatrix[s,s]
image(x=1:nrow(ccm),y=1:ncol(ccm),ccm)
text(row(ccm),col(ccm),label=round(ccm,3))
lines(i1-r[1]+1,i2-r[1]+1)
```

[image: costMatrix]

If this is the actual path taken by the DP algorithm, how can the cumulative distance along this path decrease at those points?

[image: tw]

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtw/vignettes/dtw.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the use of a "multi-step" recursion like `asymmetricP05`. Such a pattern allows the warping path to be composed of long segments, e.g. knight's moves.

To verify the monotonicity, you should *only* consider the starting positions of each of the "knight's moves" - not all of the cells passed through.   The `index1` and `index2` properties do include the intermediate cells (to provide a smoother curve), which explains your observation.

To convince yourself: (1) try another, more intuitive, pattern like `asymmetric`; and (2) note how the `stepsTaken` property has a different length than `index1/2`.